# Reasons to Keep or Disable <a href> CSS Outline

Tags: html, css, button, user-experience

When using anchors around buttons or images, they create a dotted outline if they are clicked on or in focus. I like to disable these outlines through CSS, but I have read about problems with keyboard based users (browsing a site without a mouse).

What is your experience with the outline property? I think they look incredibly trashy but I've always had qualms with disabling outlines.

Comment: I agree that they can really ruin the aesthetics of a site. I tend to show a highlight on focus so that even keyboard users will see where the focus is. In the reading that you have done, are there other problems that my approach will not solve?

Comment: The key navigation don't generate hoover event, but you do have :focus; as long as your <a> do something on focus - show to user that it is a link some way, is not a problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that users without the mouse won't be able to know which link currently has focus.

I often disable the dotted outline, but consider adding different styles for `:focus` or `:active`.